# Flex align-items: center not centering items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Flexbox `align-items: center;` is not working.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Guys, it's a copy/paste of a link for 15 lines of code. I mean, come on, it's not like he put a whole project here, you could sometimes make an effort yourselves ...

Comment: @trichetriche and what if the link is dead? and why we don't respect the SO rules ? .. or you think it's good to encourage people to post such bad question again and again. New people need to understand how to correctly write question because they need to understand that the question will be useful for new comer. We are not in a discussion forum. We all can check the link to see the code and put an answer to get reputation but this is not the purpose of the site, the purpose is to deliver high quality resources in this website.

Comment: @trichetriche and this not only the issue, a question saying *it's not working* is out of topic also. What is not working ? what is the needed output ? for me the property is working fine considering his code

Comment: "the purpose is to deliver high quality resources in this website". Such quality content for 15 lines of code ... I'm saying to losen the leash because he asked for a simple question. If you tell him to frick off, he will just do so and never come back again. Sure, you want quality content and people to respect the rules, and I agree with you. But if you want to teach him how to post, then use the review module, and don't make a sassy comment :)

Comment: @trichetriche quality is not the number of code or the content of the question ... he posted a link = the link can be modified or dead = the question will be useless and no more relevant = we have a bad questions/answer in the site. Hight quality for me is a question where we can clearly see the issue even if it's only 2 lines of code, a question that can be usefull in the futur for anyone and not only the OP

Comment: As I said, I agree with you. But if you want him to follow the rules so badly, do it yourself and use the review system. Otherwise, help him, it will take 2 minutes of your time, and other people like you will close the question for poor quality (but the man will have is answer).

Comment: @trichetriche it's already done, downvoted flagged and voted to close ;) but it's useless when he's already getting answers as he already getting what he need  and the logic for the future will be : " i will ask my bad question, i will get my answer, and i don't mind if it get closed later"

Comment: Well my purpose here is to help newcomers. What is yours ?

Comment: @trichetriche As SO have some rules that users are suppose to follow when post and answer questions, are they only for the one's who want to follow them, and the rest do how they want?

Comment: @TemaniAfif If the question is the first a user posted, be nice, not ironic, and do what I do sometimes, add comment what we expect and update their question.

Comment: Again, as I said, I agree with him (and you). But you can't force people to be smart, so you must play along with it. I too downvoted and asked for closing the question, but that didn't stop me from helping this man who otherwise would have got no help. And sassy comments won't help him get better at posting, nor will a closed question without answer.

Comment: @Halit Güvenilir It appears you have updated the codepen with a fix, so it now works. This is bad, as now the question is useless to other users, as it actually now does work properly.

Comment: @trichetriche If you plan to post an answer to an incomplete question, do the edit as well, or else, as now happened, the original codepen has been altered and suddenly work. Because if this, both the question and answers is useless to future users, as they now both work and use proper properties.

Comment: I agree and I give you an apology, I should have edited the post as well (aswell ? I never know). But as a matter of fact, for me, it wasn't incomplete, just badly formatted :)

Comment: @trichetriche Great :) .... and a question that need help with code, and where the code is not _within_ the question, is, according to SO rules, incomplete. If it would have had the code within, the correction OP made to the external code wouldn't matter, as it does now.

Comment: @trichetriche ... and maybe it should be "a swell" :)

Comment: I highly doubt that :P

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's not working becase `align-self` property is used instead of `align-items`. If you keep `align-items` and apply a `height` to the `container` you can see it working. [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/NyPPbQ)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: To apply `align-items`, height should be applied to the container. I was never aware of it.

Comment: Why is specifying a height necessary? Why can't layout work off the max height of all the items in the flex container?

Answer (score 71):

If you use the correct properties and give the `container` a height, it will work.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;

  /* CSS just to show the bounds */
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: #eee
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Make sure your container actually covers the page, otherwise it will work, but only in the current height of the container.

Comment: Best answer - that 100vh is the key to perfectly centering in all browsers.