# How to place an element (button) in the centre of a container

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to place this green button in the middle of a container, however despite my efforts I am unable to achieve this and instead it's stuck to the left. I have done some research and have done what others have suggested but still have no luck.

I have attached an image of the problem and my code so you can see what I have tried, any suggestions would be appreciated!

The problem:

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #5f7a61;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

.controls {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: centre;
  align-items: centre;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.play-btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #d5eebb;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="music-player">

  <h1 class="music-name">song one</h1>
  <p class="artist-name">artist</p>

  <div class="disk"></div>

  <div class="song-slider">
    <input type="range" value="0" class="seek-bar">
    <span class="current-time">00:00</span>
    <span class="song-duration">00:00</span>
  </div>

  <div class="controls">
    <button class="play-btn">
         <span></span>
         <span></span>       
     </button>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- FORM BODY-->
```

Comment: Could you please copy the code in your answer instead of the picture? And maybe add more code, so we could help you better.

Comment: Please add the full code so we can help you. Note align-items: center; will not work if you did not give correct hight  use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516538/flex-align-items-center-not-centering-items

Comment: always try to add the full code that you have tried on your own.

Comment: I have added the full code I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the parent element of the button (`div.controls`) the following CSS styles:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This worked, Now I know what the cause of this was I can see how simple it was.

Comment: Great! @GamingWay  You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can add these css attributes to your .music-player class.

```
.music-player{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;    
}
```

```css
  * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background: #5f7a61;
      font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    .music-player{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;    
    }

    .controls {
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .play-btn {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #d5eebb;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="music-player">

      <h1 class="music-name">song one</h1>
      <p class="artist-name">artist</p>

      <div class="disk"></div>

      <div class="song-slider">
        <input type="range" value="0" class="seek-bar">
        <span class="current-time">00:00</span>
        <span class="song-duration">00:00</span>
      </div>

      <div class="controls">
        <button class="play-btn">
             <span></span>
             <span></span>       
         </button>
      </div>

    </div>
```